# SpeechRecognizer gives no match immediately after the start

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I'm trying to make a use of SpeechRecognizer library in my android application, and so far its work leaves me with questions. First of all, it doesn't stop when I stop speaking. 
If I try to stop speech recognizing myself, the next time it gives me 'No match!' right away.

My question is: when I use google speech recognition (f. e. when I search on web), it works like a charm. In my app it is far from perfect, though the library is the same. What is wrong with my implementation?

My code (simplified):

Note: I try to use partial results to make speech recognition more flexible, but I can't see any effect except recognition became little faster.

```
    public void setupVoiceRecognition(Activity activity) {
        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(activity.getApplicationContext());
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);

        mRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                activity.getPackageName());
        mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS,
                true);
        mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 5000);
        mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 3000);
        mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
        mContext = activity.getApplicationContext();
        if (mMainBtn != null) {
            mMainBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View view) {
                    VoiceRecognition.this.onClick();
                }
            });
        }
    }    

    public void forceStop() {
        if (mListening) {
            toggleListening(false);
        }
    }    

    public void onClick() {            
        toggleListening(!mListening);            
    }


    private void toggleListening(boolean start) {
        mPartialLength = 0;
        if (start) {
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mRecognizerIntent);
        } else {
            mSpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
        }
        if (mMainBtn != null) {
            mMainBtn.setImageResource((start) ? R.drawable.icon_record_active : R.drawable.icon_record_white);
        }
        if (mSupportBtn != null) {
            mSupportBtn.setImageResource((start) ? R.drawable.icon_record_active : R.drawable.icon_record_white);
        }
        mListening = start;
    }

   ...

    @Override public void onError(int i) {
        if (mListening) {
            String errorText;
            switch (i) {
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
                    errorText = MyApp.getContext().getString(R.string.speech_recognition_err3);
                    break;

                ...

            }
            MyApp.showToast(errorText);
            toggleListening(false);
            if (i == NO_MATCH)  {
                toggleListening(true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
        ArrayList<String> matches = bundle
                .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        if (matches != null) {
            String fullText = mViewForText.getText().toString();
            mViewForText.setText(fullText.substring(0, fullText.length() - mPartialLength) + matches.get(0) + " ");
            mViewForText.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            mViewForText.setSelection(mViewForText.getText().length());
            mPartialLength = 0;
            forceStop();
        }
    }

    @Override public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {
        ArrayList<String> matches = bundle
                .getStringArrayList(EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS);
        if (matches != null) {
            mViewForText.setText(mViewForText.getText().toString() + matches.get(0) + " ");
            mPartialLength +=  matches.get(0).length() + 1;
            mViewForText.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            mViewForText.setSelection(mViewForText.getText().length());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google disabled continuous speech recognition via SpeechRecognizer for third party apps. I assume that is because they have paid API now (https://cloud.google.com/speech/) which works very well but not free.

About NO_MATCH error. Google hears own beep invitation signal and assumes it is the speech start. Such as that beep can't be recognized it returns NO_MATCH error.

There is an option. You may downgrade Google app to have more stable work of the recognition service. The last properly working version of the Google app is 6.2.34

Comment: Is there any link that can confirm this?

Comment: @JaydeepW i don't know any links confirming that. It is my own experience only.